# "phpMyAdmin" for Cassandra

Tags: tools, nosql, cassandra

Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin for RDBMS-MySQL for a Cassandra DB?

I know that there is less "runtime" config possible (column families can not be edited at runtime etc.). Nevertheless, it would be very helpful to have a GUI to inspect the different column families, browse data, and so forth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like my Cassandra Cluster Admin is exactly what you want! Take a look at it here: https://github.com/sebgiroux/Cassandra-Cluster-Admin

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I've been looking around for a good Cassandra UI and found [cassandra-web](https://github.com/avalanche123/cassandra-web). It's a Ruby gem that works very well even with the most recent versions of Cassandra.

I created a repo to add this to Docker: https://github.com/kjenney/docker-cassandra-web

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question directly, may I suggest you read these [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332113/switching-from-mysql-to-cassandra-pros-cons) regarding Cassandra db as they can be very enlightening as far as why your search may be coming up empty.

[CouchDB has a very nice GUI front end called "Futon"](http://couchdb.apache.org/screenshots.html) that may be an answer if you're looking for GUI inspection of data on a NoSQL source.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I chose Cassandra because of the absense of a single-point-of-failure which is very important in my use case...